# Magento 2.1 How do I create form component field custom depends on another field value?

Tags: magento-2.1, uicomponent, ui-form

I have one field select which has some options. One of them will have some fields depend on value, another field will hidden. I have copied and extended component js for my field but it didn't work or I did it wrong way. Ui component supports this feature? How I can achieve this?

Below is what I have done:

```
<field name="field1">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Namespace\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\Options</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Field name</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">item</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">field1</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Pathto/js/form/element/options</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>

<field name="field2Depend1"></field>
<field name="field3Depend1"></field>
```

jsComponent `js/form/element/options`:

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function (_, uiRegistry, select) {
    'use strict';

    return select.extend({

        onChange: function () {
            this.enableDisableFields();
        },

        /**
         * Enable/disable fields on Coupons tab
         */
        enableDisableFields: function () {
            // code check field
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this (**Note**: Don't forget to replace the line "Namespace" and the line "ModuleName" with your values):

```
<field name="field1">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Namespace\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\Options</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Parent Option</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Namespace_ModuleName/js/form/element/options</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">item</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">field1</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">210</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>

<field name="field2Depend1">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Field 1</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">item</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">220</item>
            <item name="breakLine" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="visibleValue" xsi:type="string">2</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
<field name="field3Depend1">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Field 2</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">item</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">230</item>
            <item name="breakLine" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="visibleValue" xsi:type="string">0</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Where:

- The child elements visibility is set by default as `false`;
- The `visibleValue` - is `field1` value when element should be
  visible;

> Namespace\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\Options

```
namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;

class Options implements ArrayInterface
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [
            0 => [
                'label' => 'Please select',
                'value' => 0
            ],
            1 => [
                'label' => 'Option 1',
                'value' => 1
            ],
            2  => [
                'label' => 'Option 2',
                'value' => 2
            ],
            3 => [
                'label' => 'Option 3',
                'value' => 3
            ],
        ];

        return $options;
    }
}
```

> app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/web/js/form/element/options.js

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function (_, uiRegistry, select, modal) {
    'use strict';

    return select.extend({

        /**
         * On value change handler.
         *
         * @param {String} value
         */
        onUpdate: function (value) {
            console.log('Selected Value: ' + value);

            var field1 = uiRegistry.get('index = field2Depend1');
            if (field1.visibleValue == value) {
                field1.show();
            } else {
                field1.hide();
            }

            var field2 = uiRegistry.get('index = field3Depend1');
            if (field2.visibleValue == value) {
                field2.show();
            } else {
                field2.hide();
            }

            return this._super();
        },
    });
});
```

Result:

Value 0 selected:
[image: Value 0 selected]

Value 1 selected:
[image: Value 1 selected]

Value 2 selected:
[image: Value 2 selected]

Value 3 selected:
[image: Value 3 selected]

**PS:** Possibly it not the best solution, but it shall help you

Comment: onUpdate is working well, but how to make onLoad? How to get field1.value?

Comment: @zhartaunik I think you should use the `initialize` method in your case becouse ui-element has no `onLoad` method. You can get any field value in any place from the registry using the input index key: `uiRegistry.get('index = field1')`. In case you have more questions, please, address me in skype (sarj1989) it will be easier to communicate in Russian.

Comment: Thanks @Siarhey. I decided to use initialize. this._super, than add necessary verification.

Comment: I can't get field value when i am using  initialize method value is "undefined".

Comment: @SaurabhJain Can you show your code (xml)?

Comment: yup sure can you share your email address.

Comment: @SaurabhJain siarhey.uchukhlebau@gmail.com

Comment: it's working fine but I need to click every time to show and hide fields. I need it based on field data onload page. I used below answer, use initialize: function but it's show field is undefined error in console.

Comment: @PrincePatel Could you ask a new question with additional information about your problem? I'll try to help you.

Comment: You can find out here also http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html

Comment: You can get selected value on load by using this.value() to initialize.

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau Is it possible to show/hide fieldset based on the value?

Comment: @JancyAbraham sure, but you should modify the fieldset component to make it dependent.

Comment: @JancyAbraham is there separate question about this? If yes, please, send me a link and I'll try to write answer.

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau Here is the link
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250747/magento-2-admin-ui-form-fieldset-dependency

Comment: @Siarhey Uchukhlebau Can I add checkbox instead?

Comment: @Siarhey did u find any solution to do this

Answer (score 12):

This is an old question with multiple answers that work, however I have discovered a solution using what Magento provides (as of 2.1.0) without the need for extending components. As multiple questions have been marked as duplicate and directed here I thought it would be beneficial to provide some information on this  option.

All form element ui components that extend `Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract.js` have a `switcherConfig` setting available for purposes such as hiding/showing elements as well as other actions. The `switcher` component can be found at [Magento_Ui/js/form/switcher](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/form/switcher.js) for the curious. You can find examples of it being used in [sales_rule_form.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/SalesRule/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_rule_form.xml#L158) and [catalog_rule_form.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/CatalogRule/view/adminhtml/ui_component/catalog_rule_form.xml#L213). Of course if you are using your own custom component already you can still use this as long as your component eventually extends `abstract` which appears to be the case based on the example code provided in the question.

Now for a more specific example to answer the original question.

In `Namespace/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/your_entity_form.xml` you simply need to add the following to the field's `settings` that does the controlling (i.e. the field that determines which fields are hidden/visible). In your example this would be `field1`.

```
<field name="field1">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        ...
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <switcherConfig>
            <rules>
                <rule name="0">
                    <value>2</value>
                    <actions>
                        <action name="0">
                            <target>your_entity_form.your_entity_form.entity_information.field2Depend1</target>
                            <callback>show</callback>
                        </action>
                        <action name="1">
                            <target>your_entity_form.your_entity_form.entity_information.field3Depend1</target>
                            <callback>hide</callback>
                        </action>
                    </actions>
                </rule>
                <rule name="1">
                    <value>3</value>
                    <actions>
                        <action name="0">
                            <target>your_entity_form.your_entity_form.entity_information.field2Depend1</target>
                            <callback>hide</callback>
                        </action>
                        <action name="1">
                            <target>your_entity_form.your_entity_form.entity_information.field3Depend1</target>
                            <callback>show</callback>
                        </action>
                    </actions>
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </switcherConfig>
    </settings>
</field>
```

Let's break it down a little. The `switcher` component contains an array of `rules` which is what we're building out here. Each `<rule>` has a name which is a number in this example. This name is the array key/index for this item. We're using numbers as array indexes. <s>Strings should work too but I haven't tested this theory</s>.
**UPDATE** - As mentioned by @ChristopheFerreboeuf in the comments, strings to not work here. These are arrays and should start with `0`, not strings or 1.

Inside each `rule` we pass two arguments.

1. `value` - This is the value of `field1` which should trigger the `actions` defined below.
2. `actions` - Here we have another array. These are the actions to be triggered when this rule's conditions are met. Again, each `action`'s name is just the array index/key of that item.

Now each `action` has two arguments as well (with an optional 3rd).

1. `target` - This is the element you wish to manipulate under this action. If you aren't familiar with how ui_component element names are composed in Magento you can check out [Alan Storm's article](https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_introducing_ui_components/). It's basically something like `{component_name}.{component_name}.{fieldset_name}.{field_name}` in this example.
2. `callback` - Here is the action to be taken on the above mentioned `target`. This callback should be a function that is available on the element targeted. Our example uses `hide` and `show`. This is where you can start to expand on the functionality available. The `catalog_rule_form.xml` example I mentioned earlier uses `setValidation` if you wish to see a different example.
3. You can also add `<params>` to any `action` that calls for them. You can see this in the `catalog_rule_form.xml` example as well.

Finally the last item inside `switcherConfig` is `<enabled>true</enabled>`. This should be pretty straight forward, it's a Boolean to enable/disable the switcher functionality we just implemented.

And we're done. So using the example above what you should see is field `field2Depend1` displayed if you choose an option with value `2` on `field1`, and `field3Depend1` displayed if you choose an option with value `3`.

I have tested this example using only `hide` and `show` on a required field and it does appear to take visibility into account for validation. In other words, if `field2Depend1` is required it will only be required when visible. No need for further configuration for that to work.

Hope this provides some help for anyone looking for a more out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: "Strings should work too but I haven't tested this theory." I accidentally tested and it does not... Actions are as rules array that needs to begin with action 0 or rule 0 not 1 or a string...

Comment: correct answer, but i've found in here that we can replace `your_entity_form.your_entity_form` with `${ $.ns }.${ $.ns }` so it can read automatically. https://cedcommerce.com/blog/use-of-switcherconfig-how-to-show-hide-ui-elements-basis-another-fields-value/

Comment: Ah, nice @fudu . I didn't think the javascript syntax would work in the xml, but it makes total sense, as it is a ui component file. Mixing xml and javascript still throws me off.

Answer (score 10):

The solution suggested by Magentix will throw an error from time to time when using initialize. It depends on the time it takes for your browser to render the components. In order to fix it you could use setTimeout.

See the code below:

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function (_, uiRegistry, select, modal) {
    'use strict';

    return select.extend({

        /**
         * Extends instance with defaults, extends config with formatted values
         *     and options, and invokes initialize method of AbstractElement class.
         *     If instance's 'customEntry' property is set to true, calls 'initInput'
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.resetVisibility();

            return this;
        },

        toggleVisibilityOnRender: function (visibility, time) {
            var field = uiRegistry.get('index = field_to_toggle');
            if(field !== undefined) {
                if(visibility == 1) {
                    field.show();
                } else {
                    field.hide();
                }

                return;
            }
            else {
                var self = this;
                setTimeout(function() {
                    self.toggleVisibilityOnRender(visibility, time);
                }, time);
            }
        },

        /**
         * On value change handler.
         *
         * @param {String} value
         */
        onUpdate: function (value) {
            if (value == 1) {
                this.showField();
            } else {
                this.hideField();
            }
            return this._super();
        },

        resetVisibility: function () {
            if (this.value() == 1) {
                this.showField();
            } else {
                this.hideField();
            }
        },

        showField: function () {
            this.toggleVisibilityOnRender(1, 1000);

        },

        hideField: function () {
            this.toggleVisibilityOnRender(0, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Its working properly.

Answer (score 7):

There's a lot of answers for this question, but most of them make either make assumptions on whether the uiRegistry is fully loaded, or use `setTimeout` to clear the call stack, and wait for the next eventloop (which in my opinion is still the wrong way to do it - since you can't be sure when the other ui components have loaded - correct me if I'm wrong).

Firstly, of course, add your custom JS component to the field config (see other answers for details):

```
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Namespace_ModuleName/js/form/element/options</item>
```

Then, here's the custom UI component that hides or shows the dependent fields - with comments to explain what's happening.

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select'
], function (_, uiRegistry, select) {

    'use strict';

    return select.extend({

        /**
         * Array of field names that depend on the value of 
         * this UI component.
         */
        dependentFieldNames: [
            'my_field_name1',
            'my_field_name2'
        ],

        /**
         * Reference storage for dependent fields. We're caching this
         * because we don't want to query the UI registry so often.
         */
        dependentFields : [],

        /**
         * Initialize field component, and store a reference to the dependent fields.
         */
        initialize: function() {
            this._super();

            // We're creating a promise that resolves when we're sure that all our dependent
            // UI components have been loaded. We're also binding our callback because
            // we're making use of `this`
            uiRegistry.promise(this.dependentFieldNames).done(_.bind(function() {

                // Let's store the arguments (the UI Components we queried for) in our object
                this.dependentFields = arguments;

                // Set the initial visibility of our fields.
                this.processDependentFieldVisibility(parseInt(this.initialValue));
            }, this));
        },

        /**
         * On value change handler.
         *
         * @param {String} value
         */
        onUpdate: function (value) {
            // We're calling parseInt, because in JS "0" evaluates to True
            this.processDependentFieldVisibility(parseInt(value));
            return this._super();
        },

        /**
         * Shows or hides dependent fields.
         *
         * @param visibility
         */
        processDependentFieldVisibility: function (visibility) {
            var method = 'hide';
            if (visibility) {
                method = 'show';
            }

            // Underscore's invoke, calls the passed method on all the objects in our array
            _.invoke(this.dependentFields, method);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have got error like `Field is Undefined` when initialized field visibility, Use `setTimeout()` to load that depended fields:

```
fieldDepend: function (value) {
     setTimeout(function(){ 
        var field1 = uiRegistry.get('index = field2');

        if (field1.visibleValue == value) {
               field1.show();
        } else {
               field1.hide();
        }

       var field2 = uiRegistry.get('index = field3');

        if (field2.visibleValue == value) {
              field2.show();
        } else {
              field2.hide();
        }    
     }, 1);
     return this._super();
},
```

Comment: Instead of setTimeout, use asynchronous method of getting dependencies instead: `uiRegistry.get('q', function(field) { ... }));`

Comment: Insted of suggesting in comment and down-vote my answer you can Post here your answer bro, This is not the way to devote any answer, You are just suggesting different way, my answer is not wrong. @Erfan. your down-vote make wrong impression.

Comment: @RonakChauhan - Agreed on point !!! your answer is not incorrect , different people have different opinion , suggestion and solution. Your answer is also correct !!

Comment: Waiting one second to initialise, and blocking initialisation is quite clearly the wrong way to do it. How do you even know your dependencies will be loaded in one second? Why won't it be two seconds? You're making an assumption here, that's best avoided.

Comment: I have not set 1 second here, Its in millisecond, SetTimeout() will just load my code after load the page, And if you have your answer then you can post it. Down-vote someone's answer is not the way to prove yourself right!@Erfan

Comment: I'm not making any assumption here, I have applied the solution and then I posted here. So you better try it and then comment here @Erfan or you have a choice to post your own code!

Comment: Sorry - my bad. I see what's happening here. With a `setTimeout`  of 1 millisecond (even 0 ms is possible), you're clearing the call stack and waiting for the next eventloop. Since the initialization of ui components is synchronous (is it?), it's likely that all fields will be loaded. I'm still not sure whether init of ui components is fully synchronous though - what if it's using custom JS, and it needs to load the file? Will the uiRegistry correctly return the field even though it's waiting for a network request? It might work for you.. I'll post my own answer soon. Thanks

Comment: Also, I've tried to remove my downvote, but it says it's locked in

Comment: It's ok, yeah you're can post your answer. I also can learn from your answer.

Comment: @RonakChauhan, thanks. I've posted my answer here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/195366/122 I can remove downvote when answer has been edited.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways for handling field dependencies, for simple Yes/No dropdown, a checkbox or a switcher, you can use the `imports` or `exports` linking properties in Magento 2. The solution is discussed in detail here: [Dependent fields in UI component forms in Magento 2 without Javascript for boolean fields](https://www.hungersoft.com/info/dependent-fields-ui-component-form-magento2-boolean-fields):

```xml
<!-- In the parent field <settings>...</settings> -->
<exports>
    <link name="checked">${$.parentName}.description:disabled</link>
</exports>

<!-- or -->

<!-- In the dependent field <settings>...</settings> -->
<imports>
    <link name="disabled">${$.parentName}.is_active:checked</link>
</imports>
```

To handle other type of values such as dependency on a list of values in a dropdown or although unlikely, a value of an input field, you can use the `switcherConfig`. Check [Dependent fields in ui-component forms in Magento 2 without Javascript](https://www.hungersoft.com/info/dependent-fields-ui-component-form-magento2-without-js) for information.

```xml
<switcherConfig>
    <rules>
        <rule name="0">
            <value>list</value><!-- Actions defined will be trigger when the current selected field value matches the value defined here-->
            <actions>
                <action name="0">
                    <target>hs_xml_dependentfield_model_form.hs_xml_dependentfield_model_form.general.list</target>
                    <callback>visible</callback>
                    <params>
                        <param name="0" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                    </params>
                </action>
                <action name="1">
                    <target>hs_xml_dependentfield_model_form.hs_xml_dependentfield_model_form.general.hex_code</target>
                    <callback>visible</callback>
                    <params>
                        <param name="0" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                    </params>
                </action>
            </actions>
        </rule>
        ...
    </rules>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
</switcherConfig>
```

The above 2 rules, handle pretty much everything using XML config. For more complex rules, you can use JavaScript as well.

Each field in the UI component form is a component which can be extended using the `component` attribute for the `<field component="path to your js" ...>...</field>`. You can then use the field `data.config` to pass more information to the component, in case the component is generic and is re-used in multiple places, combined with the `imports` or `exports` linking property to pass values to observables or methods.

For more information on the linking properties you can check [Linking properties of UI components](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_linking_concept.html#string_templ)

Answer (score 2):

Custom component with init:

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function (_, uiRegistry, select, modal) {
    'use strict';

    return select.extend({

        /**
         * Init
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.fieldDepend(this.value());

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * On value change handler.
         *
         * @param {String} value
         */
        onUpdate: function (value) {
            this.fieldDepend(value);

            return this._super();
        },

        /**
         * Update field dependency
         *
         * @param {String} value
         */
        fieldDepend: function (value) {
            var field = uiRegistry.get('index = field_to_toggle');

            if (value == 'xxxxx') {
                field.show();
            } else {
                field.hide();
            }

            return this;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it's show "field is undefined" after using initialize function.

Comment: Use `setTimeout()` in `fieldDepend()` because depended is not loaded yet.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone struggles with the ***Erfan*** solution, you have to pass the full path to the fields in `dependentFieldNames`, e.g.:

```
       dependentFieldNames: [
        'form_name.form_name.fieldset.field_name',
        'form_name.form_name.fieldset.field_name1',
        'form_name.form_name.fieldset.field_name2',
        'form_name.form_name.fieldset.field_name3'
    ],
```

I'm not sure why form_name has to be 2 times, but this has worked for me.

To debug this I put `console.log(query);` in `static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/registry/registry.js` 223rd line ( the get() function just before `this._addRequest(query, callback)` )