# Magento 2 Admin Form Field

Tags: magento2, adminform, uicomponent

To create form in admin magento is now using the same UI component as it use it for grid.

I have one select which will have its dependent elements.

How can I achieve this in ui component

```
<field name="is_external_redirect">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Namespace\Module\Model\Config\Source\Options</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select One</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">geoip</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">country_codes</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">0</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Comment: You can see this related [post](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132020/magento-2-1-how-do-i-create-form-component-field-custom-depends-on-another-field).
Hope this will help you