# Magento 2 admin form creation

Tags: magento2

I am creating Form in Magento2 admin with UI Component.

I need to add dependency to fields and dependent field values what to load dynamically.

In Below link they are hard coding visible value but here i need to get selected value dynamically and from that value i need to get collection from database and append that collection to dependent drop down.

[magento 2.1 How do i create form component field custom depends on another field value](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132020/magento-2-1-how-do-i-create-form-component-field-custom-depends-on-another-field)

Comment: here option id is hard coded in "field2Depend1" but i want to pass value dynamically and from that value i need to get collection from database