# Magento 2.3 : using swicher config

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I have used this in my custom module and this is working.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/256280/55674

What i want to know is if there is a way to show/hide an entire fieldset using above method.

Can anyone provide a better way for that?
Thanks

Comment: I haven't tested this, but in theory if you address the fieldset in the `<target>` area I would think it would work.

Comment: no it doesn't work.any idea guys ?

Comment: Yeah looking at the `fieldset.js` and `collapsible.js` components they don't extend `abstract.js` which means they own't have the switcher config props and functions. The only suggestion I can think would be to extend the fieldset component and add in the switcher config stuff yourself and set your fieldset to use your component instead of default. Not sure if that's the best approach.