# How to hide the ui component field using form modifier on condition in magento2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I have two ui component filed :

i want to make visibility false of second component if first's value is true

how to use Form modifier in magento2 ui

Comment: Try this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132020/magento-2-1-how-do-i-create-form-component-field-custom-depends-on-another-field

Comment: @SukumarGorai thanks for reference , i have already see this example it's working fine for input filed but i am not able to get value form registry when fiels is image or wysiwyg editor
var field1 = uiRegistry.get('index = field2Depend1');